# Something in the TV

Tags: riddle, wordplay

There is one answer that satisfies the title, and all of the lines below.

> I can bow to the enemy.
>   I am the opposite of myself.
>   I can help you, if you want to go back.
>   I am known for staying in a group of my kind.

What am I?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The answer is possibly...

> **The letter U** 
>  
>  *I can bow to the enemy*: U = Yew, commonly used to make bows.
>  *I am the opposite of myself*: U = You, the opposite of "myself"
>  *I can help you, if you want to go back*: [U-Turn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-turn).
>  *I am known for staying in a group of my kind*: U = Ewe, who usually group together in herds.
>  The title: the letter U is between T and V in the English alphabet.

Comment: The fourth line could be rot13(gur yrggre J vf cebabhaprq "qbhoyr H" va Ratyvfu)

Comment: @NudgeNudge Good! Lines 2, 3 and Title are right. For lines 1 and 4, look for spelling variations of the answer (like you did with line 2).

Answer (score 4):

I know there is an accepted answer, but this came to mind:

> **Beam**  
>  
>  *I can **bow** to the **enemy***: The beam in a television tube is **bent** magnetically to change the position on the **opposing** screen that it is **shot** at
>  *I am the **opposite** of myself*: A beam is something you **send**, but also something **received** 
>   - - It is also something **tangible** (a wooden support beam) and something **intangible** (sunbeam)
>  *I can help you, if you want to **go back***: "**Beam me up,** Scotty"
>  *I am known for **staying in a group** of **my kind***: A laser beam is **all one frequency** of light, all going in the **same direction**.
>  The title: as mentioned it is used in tube TV technology.